# "of the" or "of" in mathematical contex?

Tags: grammar

On Wikipedia of the Expected Value:

> In probability theory, the expected value is a generalization **of the** weighted average.

Is "the" necessary there? If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strictly speaking necessary but you might want to consider th balance of the sentence.

> In probability theory, the expected value is a generalization of the weighted average.

Both expected value and weighted average have a preceding *the*

> In probability theory, expected value is a generalization of weighted average.

Now neither has. To me having one with and one without sounds awkward.